# Highchart doesn't display selected data properly

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

This is a reproduce code: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-banzai-55j8b?file=/src/LineGraph.js

When I select **210C**  key in **Aggregated Key** drop down list, the chart display **green** line.

[image]

Then, I select **2104** key in **Graph Key** drop down list, the graph displays **orange** line.But the **210C** line is disappeard and when I hover on **210C-aggregated** it shows **2104** line.

[image]

**Aggregated Key**: show the accumulative data by time

Comment: I am afraid that I don't understand clearly where the problem is. Could you describe the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Hi @SebastianWędzel, I add more details about the problem.

Comment: jasonB - I tried to simplify your code for better understanding if the problem is on the Highcharts side or on your custom code, but it seems that you render the Highcharts component too many times, it's a really bad pattern. Check this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tgjscc?file=LineGraph.js The component should be mounted only once. Please try to fix your code, then we will be able to focus on the Highcharts.

Comment: hi @SebastianWędzel, even I simplyfy, the issue still appears. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pm4bxr?file=LineGraph.js

Comment: I print out the chartOptions before it's applied to Highchart. The series data is correct but it doesn't display properly when apply the data to Highchart. I'm not sure how to fix the code

Comment: jasonB - I am almost sure that something is wrong with calculating in your code. Do the following steps - open the demo which you have shared in the previous comment, add 210C aggregated - see that the data.length is 319, next add the 2105 Graph Key data, now check the console - the aggregated data.length has been changed to the 191. Highcharts doesn't have any impact for it.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel if you comment the HighchartsReact component, you can see the aggregated.data.length of 210C-aggregated is 319 and 2105 is 191. But if you uncomment Highchart component, the data length of  210C-aggregated and 2105 is the same 191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging I found out that the problem is with re-rendering updated props and Highcharts wrapper has an issue with it.

Using the immutable flag should solve the issue:

```
return <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} immutable={true}/>;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-shannon-txyum

Simplified version: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ywda6g?file=LineGraph.js

API: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react#options-details

You can also try to combine with the `OneToOne` flag.

Comment: Another issue, I add a function ```onMouseOver``` to set the ```currentMarker``` value since I want to pass  ```currentMarker``` to another Map component . The error appears when I hover points on the plot. This is a reproduce code https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-qefpyq?file=Analytics.js You can uncomment from line 54-56 to see the error

Comment: Why do you need to keep this in the state? Why not define a global variable and keep it there  https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-majaao?file=Analytics.js ? I think that the problem is with your rerendering chart too many times, each state change rerenders the chart. As I mentioned before - it's a bad pattern. In my way of implementation, it works fine - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xe2typ?file=Analytics.js

Comment: If I define a global variable, the ```currentMarker``` doesn't update on ```Map``` component https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h8bmea?file=Analytics.js . Is there anyway that I can pass the value ```currentMarker``` to ```Map``` component by using class component instead of Hooks since I have to update lots of components to be Hooks and it costs time a lot.

Comment: I tried to transform to Hooks but it's a big project and has lots of nested components so it would be great if I can use Class component instead of Hooks

Comment: @jasonB it doesn't matter if the config is created with Hooks or Class components. Take a look at this simplified demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-lenygu?file=Analytics.js What's important is to render the chart component only once.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thanks a lot !